# How to split a string on basis of 'and' or 'or' in python?

Tags: python, regex, split, tree, nlp

Suppose I have a string s = SU 3180 and (CMG 3200 or SU 3210). I need to split this string into a tree diagram such as this:

```
               X
              / \
       SU 3180   ()
                / - \
        CMG 3200     SU 3210
```

The main goal is to show a difference with and / or split as show in the diagram. For example I have shown the or split with hyphen between the split. I have no idea how I should proceed with this. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: You have a number of problems to solve: you need to deal with parentheses, order of precedence, recursively or iteratively parsing long strings and finally printing a representation of it that's properly laid out - that's a bit much to ask for in a single question without an attempt at solving it yourself. Please provide code you tried yourself and ask from there.

Comment: You need to write a parser for this, and that is probably the point of your assignment.  Regex is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I agree with Grismar, we need to see what you have already, as this is a pretty complicated question and it's easier to help that way. That being said, you could look into a grammar parser like [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Most parsers use regex for tokenizing though.

Answer (score 2):

For algorithmic processing of that string, I'm not sure, for just that one case, you can likely start with this simple expression,

```
([A-Z]+\s+\d+)\s+and\s+\(([A-Z]+\s+\d+)\s+or\s+([A-Z]+\s+\d+)\)
```

and replace it with something similar to:

> ```
>            X\n               /\\\n        \1  ()\n               /  -  \\\n       \2       \3
> ```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"([A-Z]+\s+\d+)\s+and\s+\(([A-Z]+\s+\d+)\s+or\s+([A-Z]+\s+\d+)\)"

string = "SU 3180 and (CMG 3200 or SU 3210)"

subst = '               X\\n               /\\\\\\n        \\1  ()\\n               /  -  \\\\\\n       \\2       \\3'

print(re.sub(regex, subst, string))
```

#### Output

```
           X
           /\
    SU 3180  ()
           /  -  \
   CMG 3200       SU 3210
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/48m0It/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/48m0It/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

A bit more complex expression that you can start with could be using `(?R)` to check for balanced brackets, then capture what is before and after brackets, level by level (depth), pass it through a for loop, and based on that design some methods to print the tree level by level, which is pretty complicated:

```
(?>([^(]*?)\s*([(]([^()]*|(?R))*[)])([^)]*?)\s*)
```

or

```
([^(]*?)\s*([(]([^()]*|(?R))*[)])([^)]*?)\s*
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/36nHHX/1/)

#### Reference

[Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

Comment: it will work only on this specific input, but not an arbitrary tree